# Implement Web pages plugin in InnoSetup script

Tags: web, inno-setup

I tried to implement Tlama webpages plugin ([web plugin](http://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/#svn/trunk)). in my inno setup with no success, i use the unicode inno version 
I receive the following  massage - [image]

here is my code -

```
[Setup]
...
[Files]
Source:"WebBrowser.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
const
  EVENT_BEFORE_NAVIGATE = 1;

var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;

type
  TWebBrowserEventProc = procedure(EventCode: Integer; URL: WideString);

procedure CreateWebBrowser(ParentWnd: HWND; Left, Top, Width, Height: Integer; 
  CallbackProc: TWebBrowserEventProc);
  external 'CreateWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';
procedure DestroyWebBrowser;
  external 'DestroyWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';
procedure ShowWebBrowser(Visible: Boolean);
  external 'ShowWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';
procedure NavigateWebBrowser(URL: WideString);
  external 'NavigateWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';

procedure OnWebBrowserEvent(EventCode: Integer; URL: WideString); 
begin
  if EventCode = EVENT_BEFORE_NAVIGATE then
    MsgBox(URL, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Web Browser Page', 
    'This page contains web browser');
  CreateWebBrowser(WizardForm.InnerPage.Handle, 0, WizardForm.Bevel1.Top, 
    WizardForm.InnerPage.ClientWidth, WizardForm.InnerPage.ClientHeight - WizardForm.Bevel1.Top,
    @OnWebBrowserEvent);
  NavigateWebBrowser('http://www.google.com');
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  DestroyWebBrowser;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  ShowWebBrowser(CurPageID = CustomPage.ID);
end;
```

Please aid me on this , thanks

Comment: I was hoping no one will ever use it :) Well, but I cannot reproduce it with Inno Setup 5.5.5 (u) on my Windows 7 64-bit system (with latest updates applied). Which system do you have ? Which line causes this error ?

Comment: I run Windows 7 64-bit system, as for the error line, i don't know, it probably a problem with the dll code as seen in the error massage (I guess so)

Comment: Yes, it looks like a problem with that DLL's function import. But I can't tell you why. Your imports are correct and your script worked fine for me when I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another solution (made by a japanese dvp) with

Blog here : [Innosetup webctrl v2.1](http://restools.hanzify.org/article.asp?id=90)

Download here : [inno_webctrl_v2.1.zip](http://restools.hanzify.org/inno/webctrl/inno_webctrl_v2.1.zip)

---

Example.iss

```vb
; restools
; http://restools.hanzify.org
; 插件名：webctrl.dll
; 插件功能：网络连接检测，创建网页页面。
; 插件大小：9 KB

; V2 增强操作函数，可以同时创建多达 256 个 Web 窗口。
; V2 例子中演示了建立一个小型浏览器以体现该版本中的函数如何使用。比起 V1 重点在于能同时创建多个 Web 窗口。
; V2.1 删除 InitWebCtrl 和 UninitWebCtrl 函数, 增加 FreeAllWebWnd. 改善某些情况下不能卸载插件的问题.

[Setup]
AppName=My Application
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Application
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "webctrl.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "file.htm"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "wizard.htm"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "1.gif"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "2.gif"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "3.gif"; Flags: dontcopy

[code]
function GetSystemMetrics(nIndex: Integer): Integer; external 'GetSystemMetrics@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer): Longint; external'GetWindowLongA@user32.dll stdcall';
function SetWindowLong(Wnd: HWnd; Index: Integer; NewLong: Longint): Longint; external'SetWindowLongA@user32.dll stdcall';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 检查网络连接是否正常
// lpszURL: 网址，如果这里设置为空网址，检测将会简单的检查网络状态，返回状态标志
// lpdwState: 状态标志，以下是标志值的解释
// 注意：当不用网址来检测网络连接时，只是检查当前是否符合网络连接的条件，但是并不等于
//       能正常连接 Internet，但是这种检测方式相当迅速，如果使用网址连接测试，如果网
//       络处于正常连接，检查速度也相当快，但是如果非正常，那么将会有一点时间延迟，因
//       为实际的连接测试有一个超时的限制来判断是否能够连接。但是这种检测方式是最直接
//       的，并能确实知道是否能够连接网络，所以你按照实际要求来选择检测方式。
//
//得到的 lpdwState 返回值可能是以下值的一个或几个值之和：
//  INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED           ：$00000001 连接状态；
//  INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED        ：$00000002 非连接状态（和 INTERNET_STATE_CONNECTED 对应）；
//  INTERNET_STATE_DISCONNECTED_BY_USER：$00000010 用户请求的非连接状态
//  INTERNET_STATE_IDLE                ：$00000100 连接状态，并且空闲
//  INTERNET_STATE_BUSY                ：$00000200 连接状态，正在响应连接请求
function CheckConnectState(lpsURL: PChar; var lpdwState: dword): boolean; external'checkconnectstate@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// 创建 WEB 窗口
function NewWebWnd(hWndParent: HWND; X, Y, nWidth, nHeight: Integer): HWND; external'newwebwnd@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// 释放 WEB 窗口
function FreeWebWnd(hWndWeb: HWND): Boolean; external 'freewebwnd@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// 释放所有 WEB 窗口, 此函数对于卸载插件很重要, 必须在结束安装之前调用才能顺利卸载插件.
function FreeAllWebWnd(): Boolean; external 'freeallwebwnd@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// 设置 WEB 窗口的父窗口
function WebWndSetParent(hWndWeb: HWND; hWndParent: HWND): Boolean; external'webwndsetparent@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// 设置 WEB 窗口的位置大小
function WebWndSetBounds(hWndWeb: HWND; X, Y, nWidth, nHeight: Integer): Boolean; external'webwndsetbounds@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// 显示 HTML 网页
function DisplayHTMLPage(hWndWeb: HWND; lpsURL: PChar): Boolean; external'displayhtmlpage@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';  // ;

// 显示 HTML 字符串
function DisplayHTMLStr(hWndWeb: HWND; lpsHtmlText: PChar): Boolean; external'displayhtmlstr@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

// Web 页面 动作
function WebPageAction(hWndWeb: HWND; action: DWord): Boolean; external'webpageaction@files:webctrl.dll stdcall';

const
  SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
  SM_CYSCREEN = 1;

  WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = $200;
  GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;

  WEBPAGE_GOBACK = 0;
  WEBPAGE_GOFORWARD = 1;
  WEBPAGE_GOHOME = 2;
  WEBPAGE_SEARCH = 3;
  WEBPAGE_REFRESH = 4;
  WEBPAGE_STOP = 5;
var
  UrlPage, HtmlPage, HtmlTextPage: TWizardPage;
  WebHWND1, WebHWND2, WebHWND3, WebHWND4: HWND;
  WebHWND_Browser: HWND;
  Form_Browser: TForm;
  AddrEdit: TNewEdit;
  GoBtn: TNewButton;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  WebHWND1 := 0;
  WebHWND2 := 0;
  WebHWND3 := 0;
  WebHWND4 := 0;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  WizardForm.Hide;
  FreeAllWebWnd;
end;

procedure GoBackBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebPageAction(WebHWND_Browser, WEBPAGE_GOBACK);
end;

procedure GoForwardBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebPageAction(WebHWND_Browser, WEBPAGE_GOFORWARD);
end;

procedure StopBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebPageAction(WebHWND_Browser, WEBPAGE_STOP);
end;

procedure RefreshBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebPageAction(WebHWND_Browser, WEBPAGE_REFRESH);
end;

procedure HomeBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebPageAction(WebHWND_Browser, WEBPAGE_GOHOME);
end;

procedure GoBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DisplayHTMLPage(WebHWND_Browser, AddrEdit.Text);
end;

procedure BrowserFormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  W: Integer;
begin
  WebWndSetBounds(WebHWND_Browser, 0, ScaleY(35), Form_Browser.ClientWidth,
         Form_Browser.ClientHeight - ScaleY(35));
  W := Form_Browser.Width - ScaleX(285);
  if W <= 0 then W := 1;
  AddrEdit.Width := W;
  GoBtn.SetBounds(AddrEdit.Left + AddrEdit.Width + ScaleX(2), ScaleY(5), ScaleX(30),
       WizardForm.CancelButton.Height);
end;

procedure EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
    DisplayHTMLPage(WebHWND_Browser, AddrEdit.Text);
end;

procedure WizardBtnOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight: Integer;
  Btn: TNewButton;
begin
  Form_Browser := TForm.Create(WizardForm);
  try
    Form_Browser.Caption := 'ThinBrowser';
    Form_Browser.BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu, biMaximize];
    ScreenWidth := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    ScreenHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    Form_Browser.SetBounds((ScreenWidth - ScaleX(600)) div 2, (ScreenHeight - ScaleY(400)) div2,
         ScaleX(600), ScaleY(400));
    WebHWND_Browser := NewWebWnd(Form_Browser.Handle, 0, 0, Form_Browser.ClientWidth,
         Form_Browser.ClientHeight);
    SetWindowLong(Form_Browser.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(
         WebHWND_Browser, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);

    Btn := TNewButton.Create(Form_Browser);
    Btn.SetBounds(ScaleX(5), ScaleY(5), ScaleX(40), WizardForm.CancelButton.Height);
    Btn.Caption := '&Back';
    Btn.OnClick := @GoBackBtnOnClick;
    Btn.Parent := Form_Browser;

    Btn := TNewButton.Create(Form_Browser);
    Btn.SetBounds(ScaleX(47), ScaleY(5), ScaleX(55), WizardForm.CancelButton.Height);
    Btn.Caption := '&Forward';
    Btn.OnClick := @GoForwardBtnOnClick;
    Btn.Parent := Form_Browser;

    Btn := TNewButton.Create(Form_Browser);
    Btn.SetBounds(ScaleX(104), ScaleY(5), ScaleX(40), WizardForm.CancelButton.Height);
    Btn.Caption := '&Stop';
    Btn.OnClick := @StopBtnOnClick;
    Btn.Parent := Form_Browser;

    Btn := TNewButton.Create(Form_Browser);
    Btn.SetBounds(ScaleX(146), ScaleY(5), ScaleX(50), WizardForm.CancelButton.Height);
    Btn.Caption := '&Refresh';
    Btn.OnClick := @RefreshBtnOnClick;
    Btn.Parent := Form_Browser;

    Btn := TNewButton.Create(Form_Browser);
    Btn.SetBounds(ScaleX(198), ScaleY(5), ScaleX(40), WizardForm.CancelButton.Height);
    Btn.Caption := '&Home';
    Btn.OnClick := @HomeBtnOnClick;
    Btn.Parent := Form_Browser;

    AddrEdit := TNewEdit.Create(Form_Browser);
    AddrEdit.Left := ScaleX(240);
    AddrEdit.Top := ScaleY(6);
    AddrEdit.Parent := Form_Browser;
    AddrEdit.Text := 'about:blank';
    AddrEdit.OnKeyPress := @EditKeyPress;

    GoBtn := TNewButton.Create(Form_Browser);
    GoBtn.Caption := '&Go';
    GoBtn.OnClick := @GoBtnOnClick;
    GoBtn.Parent := Form_Browser;

    BrowserFormResize(Form_Browser);
    Form_Browser.OnResize := @BrowserFormResize;
    Form_Browser.ActiveControl := AddrEdit;
    Form_Browser.ShowModal();
    FreeWebWnd(WebHWND_Browser);
  finally
    Form_Browser.Free();
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  State: DWord;
  s: string;
  BrowserBtn: TNewButton;
begin
  State := 0;
  s := '';
// 如果需要进行网址连接测试，取消下面代码的注释
//  s := 'http://www.google.cn';

  if CheckConnectState(s, State) then
    MsgBox('网络已经连接。', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox('网络未连接。', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
  MsgBox(inttostr(State), mbInformation, MB_OK);

  ExtractTemporaryFile('wizard.htm');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('file.htm');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('1.gif');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('2.gif');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('3.gif');

  WebHWND1 := NewWebWnd(WizardForm.WelcomePage.Handle, 0, 0, WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Width, WizardForm.WelcomePage.Height);
  DisplayHTMLPage(WebHWND1, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\wizard.htm'));

  UrlPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, '测试 Web 页面', '网址: http://www.google.cn');

  HtmlPage := CreateCustomPage(UrlPage.ID, '测试 HTML文件 页面', '文件: file.htm');

  HtmlTextPage := CreateCustomPage(HtmlPage.ID, '测试 HTML文本 页面', '临时自定义 HTML 字符串');

  BrowserBtn := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  BrowserBtn.Left := WizardForm.ClientWidth - WizardForm.CancelButton.Left - WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
  BrowserBtn.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
  BrowserBtn.Width := WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
  BrowserBtn.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
  BrowserBtn.Caption := '&Browser...';
  BrowserBtn.OnClick := @WizardBtnOnClick;
  BrowserBtn.Parent := WizardForm;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
    WebWndSetParent(WebHWND1, WizardForm.WelcomePage.Handle)
  else
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
    WebWndSetParent(WebHWND1, WizardForm.FinishedPage.Handle)
  else
  if (CurPageID = UrlPage.ID) and (WebHWND2 = 0) then
  begin
    WebHWND2 := NewWebWnd(UrlPage.Surface.Handle, 0, 0, UrlPage.Surface.Width, UrlPage.Surface.Height);
    DisplayHTMLPage(WebHWND2, 'http://www.google.cn')
  end else
  if (CurPageID = HtmlPage.ID) and (WebHWND3 = 0) then
  begin
    WebHWND3 := NewWebWnd(HtmlPage.Surface.Handle, 0, 0, HtmlPage.Surface.Width, HtmlPage.Surface.Height);
    DisplayHTMLPage(WebHWND3, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\file.htm'));
  end
  else
  if (CurPageID = HtmlTextPage.ID) and (WebHWND4 = 0) then
  begin
    WebHWND4 := NewWebWnd(HtmlTextPage.Surface.Handle, 0, 0, HtmlTextPage.Surface.Width, HtmlTextPage.Surface.Height);
    DisplayHTMLStr(WebHWND4, '<b>I''m a <u>HTML text</u></b>');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Works perfectly, 10x v20100v